# Paypal Express IPN failure intermittent

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, paypal-express, ipn

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 and I am having issues with the PayPal IPN. Its currently set to be https://www.example.co.uk/paypal/ipn.

1) Is https://www.example.co.uk/paypal/ipn the correct address to use?

2) How can I start to debug this issue as PayPal as saying its a issue with the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, `/paypal/ipn` is correct
2. Try enabling debug mode and see if that gives you some insight. Set `Debug Mode` to `Yes` in `Payment Methods > Paypal (edition) > Configure > Advanced Settings`

If this does not help, look at `Mage_Paypal_IpnController` and `processIpnRequest` method in `Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn` class and look for a good places to put some `Mage::log` calls.

I would also recommend that you create a PayPal Sandbox account if you don't have one already since it provides IPN request simulator.

Good luck.